# connecting to volusion store using curl functions

Tags: php, api

I have volusion store URL and I am connecting to volusion store using this URL and curl function. Following is my code to connect -

> $URL
>   ='http://v970032.y5pgm9yfhypo.demo17.volusion.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=rashmi@edreamz.in&EncryptedPassword=24EA69124482A486AF3E6BA68DDEECBB7CBC3661EA792E0DC4A40CD6FC031E6E&Import=Update';
>   $ch = curl_init($URL);

I just want to check whether the connection for the given URL is connected or not. How can I achieve this please advise me. Right now if I used -

> echo $ch

it is only displaying Resource id #2

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, `curl_init` ins't enough. You'll need to use [`curl_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) to actually send the request. Once the request is sent, you can use [`curl_errno`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) to check if an error was returned and [`curl_getinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to get more information about the request and response such as the HTTP response code (e.g.: 200, 404), how long it took to connect, etc.

**Modified example from the `curl_getinfo` documentation:**

```
<?php

// Create a curl handle
$ch = curl_init('http://v970032.y5pgm9yfhypo.demo17.volusion.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=rashmi@edreamz.in&EncryptedPassword=24EA69124482A486AF3E6BA68DDEECBB7CBC3661EA792E0DC4A40CD6FC031E6E&Import=Update');

// Tell cURL to return the transfer instead of outputting it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occured
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
    // Here, I'm outputting the value of $result but you can do whatever you'd like
    // with it such as using a DOMDocument to parse XML or HTML, json_decode to
    // parse JSON, etc.
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo 'Sorry, an error occurred while connecting to Volusion.';
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to have a look at [`curl_setopt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) and more specifically at `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and some of the other basic options you can pass to cURL. The options are well documented.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Using only URL I got the solution but actually I am connecting to volusion store with the loginn ID and password. I want to check whether the URL is connected properly or not. Its not only domain name but it also have some parameters attached to URL

Comment: @user1292325 - I don't think I understand what you're asking still because I'd give you the exact same answer again. So you want to do is very that the URL is valid and that it contains certain query string parameters prior to doing the cURL request?

Comment: yes I have the certain query string parameters which will be used as login credentials while connecting to volusion store

Comment: @user1292325 - Have a look at [`http_build_query`](http://ca.php.net/http_build_query) to create a query string from an array. If you want to make sure that the URL is valid, have a look at  [`parse_url`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) as one will parse out the parts of the URL and the other will convert the query string into an array. Using `array_key_exists` you'll be able to make sure that certain keys exist.

Comment: no I am not worried about URL validation I just want to check what values are return when connected successfully and not that's it

Comment: @Sneha - In that case, I'm assuming what you're looking for is `curl_setopt` with `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and a `curl_exec`. I've updated the example above.

Comment: still there is an issue. Event if I provide invalid credentials then also it is executing if condition not else, why this is happening I cant understand. And var $result not returning anything. Please help me

Comment: @Sneha - It's up to you to make sure that `$result` contains the right values. There's no magic method unfortunately. I have no idea what the web service is supposed to return and when I visit the URL, I get a blank page. You could add a `if (empty($result)) { echo 'No data returned.'; } else { // Do something here }` in there. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a service where you hire developers. Please post what you've tried in your question above and I (or someone else) will help you.

Comment: thanks for your reply but you did not got my point, the thing is that I want to check URL is connected or not, whatever you are talking is about the domain name. Please help

Comment: @Sneha - I'm sorry. A URL cannot be "connected". A "connection" is established between 2 devices. You can use `curl_errno` as in the example above to see if the connection succeeded or failed. You can use `curl_getinfo` to check if you got a 404 error, 500 error, etc. I'm not sure what you mean by check if a URL is connected or not. But if you get inside the `if` statement in the example above then cURL has connected and retrieved something. It's then up to you to verify that `$result` is what you expected or not.